# Asp.Net Kendo UI event functions is not defined "change is not defined"

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, user-interface, kendo-ui

I'm working with Kendo UI and I'm using the TimePicker widget. I wanted to call an onchange script while I'm changing the time. It says "change is not defined"
This is my Kendo UI code:

```
                @(Html.Kendo().TimePicker()
                  .Name("debut_h_std")
                  .Events(e =>
                     {
                         e.Change("change");
                     })
                  .Value("08:00 AM")

                )
```

and this is my change function:

```
function change() {
        alert("change")
    }
```

Thanks for your answer

Comment: let me know if my answer helps you

Answer (score 4):

**ASP.NET MVC Kendo UI widgets require you to define functions in Global Scope**

The reason it was breaking is because your function was not even defined at that instance or not in a global scope. So make sure you have your script in a global scope. you should have something like this in your razor view.

```
 @(Html.Kendo().TimePicker()
       .Name("debut_h_std")
       .Events(e =>
        {
           e.Change("change");
        })
       .Value("08:00 AM")
       )
<script>
    function change() {
      alert("change")
    }
</script>
```

If the function is directly put under the script tag then its scope is global. Make sure you have not placed the function inside another block or Not even under document ready. If its inside document ready its scope is only inside the function block of document ready.

**Also Key Point**
ASP.NET MVC Kendo UI will convert the entire razor syntax of any widget into a jquery function when the controller returns the view. And this jquery block will execute on document ready.

---

If you are using **Jquery Kendo UI** make sure all the functions are under same scope or at least accessible even if it is in different scope by making function as global scope

Answer (score 0):

I just solved it with javascript

```
 <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                function onOpen() {
                    kendoConsole.log("Open");
                }

                function onClose() {
                    kendoConsole.log("Close");
                }

                function onChange() {
                    kendoConsole.log("Change :: " + kendo.toString(this.value(), 't'));
                }

                $("#timepicker").kendoTimePicker({
                    change: onChange,
                    close: onClose,
                    open: onOpen
                });
            });
        </script>
```